# из одной базы данных в другую базу данных

Tags: c#, sql, алгоритм, entity-framework

Имеется старая база данных, создали новую базу данных и через микросервис мобильное приложение которое работает часто в режиме оффлайн и в момент сети синхронизируются данные с новой базой данных и потом новая синхронизирует со старой. Делается это все для того, что бы скопировать в течении определенного времени данные которые клиент использует и впоследствии просто удалить старую базу данных, не спрашивайте а почему сразу не иммигрировать, там все очень сложно, базе больше двадцати лет, много разных клиентов сидят на ней.

И вот замеченно, что если приложение которое работает со старой базой отключенно или bug в сети, вообщем если два api не договорили на заднем фоне, то данные просто сохраняются в новой базе и старая потом об этом ничего не узнает, а мобильное приложение отправляет мессаж что мол данные синхронизированны успешно, только вот потом не состыковка с данными случается.

Таким образом мне думается, что необходимо следующее, создать таблицу в новой базе данных с объектами, которые не удалось синхронизировать потом метод в сервисе дополнительный чтобы получать ответ от api 1 и уже при повторном подключении запускать заново объекты для обновления в данной таблице до синхронизации с мобильным приложением.

**Вопрос :  какие данные должна содержать данная таблица ? И есть ли другие решения**

```cs
        [Key]
        public long Id { get; set; }

        public long? ObjectId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey(nameof(ObjectId))]
        public Object Object { get; set; }

        public DateTime Date { get; set; } 

        // for example if error < 2, check properties, maybe some information is not correct in that object
        public int ErrorSynchronization { get; set; }
```

в старой базе данных бывают "сюрпризы" например однажды приложение выдавало ошибку при сохранении одного эллемента и я заметила, что в базе данных есть ограничения для одного из свойст (varchar 5) а клиент сохраняет например 8 символов, это не было нигде зафиксированно, как уже повторюсь база старая и не мало кто на ней работал...поэтому предусматриваю int ErrorSynchronization, например если первый, второй раз все еще остается не синхронизированным и число int думаю надо +1 возможно надо проанализировать все свойства данного объекта

*// api 2 создает таблицы через Entity Framework, работаю я на C#, база на sql => поэтому и метки соответствующие*

p.s. вопрос, а тот кто ставит минус это обосновывается, или может быть просто хоп и минус поставил, сама не ставила еще минусы поэтому интересуюсь

Comment: Чисто из любопытства: "стол" это юмор или трудности перевода?

Comment: Вы бы сказали какие данные должна содержать "таблица" верно ?

Comment: Именно так, верно

Comment: я и правда общаюсь на многих языках, и порой возможно трактовка тех или иных терминов отличается, я молодой программист и многие термины узнаю не на русском, так как обучение было тоже не всегда на русском.

Comment: Ну, если просто вбить в переводчик, то да. Table – и стол и таблица. Но база данных всё-таки содержит именно таблицы. Здесь суть даже не в переводе, а в логической организации данных. Они организованы именно по табличному принципу в реляционных БД.

Comment: Это всё к тому, что слово "стол" может ввести в заблуждение отвечающих, плохо знакомых с английским языком, т.к. в российской нотации всё-таки общепринято определение "таблица" применительно к БД

Comment: Я убрал лишнее из вопроса, пожалуйста не возвращайте больше на место. Вопрос и так объемный. А обоснование минуса на совести минусующего.

Comment: Вы убрали две строчки :
1. У меня вопрос к сообществу, хотелось бы услышать мнение профессионалов.
2. Вопрос : какие данные должен содержать данный стол ? И есть ли другие решения ПРАВКА =>

Comment: a старую таблицу кто-то еще меняет? и насколько мы это контроллируем?

Comment: старая таблица меняется в синхронизации с новой, полный контроль, то есть то, что мы изменили в новойБазе
 (api2-newDB api1-oldDB) синхронизируется между двумя api и обновляет в старой или добавляет или удаляет, НО если api1 вдруг не ответило, то данные просто сохраняются в новой базе данных, а старая об этом ничего не узнает...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно создать таблицу в новой базе данных с **задачами** на синхронизацию.

И отдельный синхронизатор, который берет задачи по очереди из новой базы, применяет к старой базе, и хранит номер последней примененной задачи в старой базе.

Изменения и номер последней примененной задачи запишутся в одной транзакции.

Comment: а таблица которую я составила подходит или нужно что-то добавить ?
...с задачами, что именно значит
отдельный синхронизатор создан и в нем я думаю как Вы верно подметили нужно events который при подключении первогоАпи будет искать данные из таблицы новБД, только хотелось бы вернуться к фразе таблица с задачами, что подразумевает

Comment: При операции в апи2 просто пишем в таблицу заданий, что нужно сделать с апи1. Не зависим от состояния апи1. Если идет 2 апдейта одной записи в главной таблице, то записей-заданий при этом 2. Похоже на redo-log. Отдельный исполнитель смотрит номер последней примененной задачи, берет следующую задачу, применяет задачу и меняет номер.

Comment: https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-streams-tables-part-1-event-streaming/

Answer (score 0):

после миграции базы данных, мы создали нашу **временную таблицу** в которой хранятся объекты для повторной синхронизации. (выше в моем вопросе есть пример того, что хранится в данной таблице)

в момент когда мы сохраняем объекты как обычно,
если вдруг api1 не ответило, мы сохраняем объекты в данной временной таблице, затем

**ДЛЯ ПОВТОРНОЙ ПОПЫТКИ ЗАПИСИ в АПИ1**

создаем дополнительный HookController

```cs
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult> RunSynchronizations()
{
    await synchronizationService.SendUnsynchronizedObjectsAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    return Ok();
}
```

а в нашем api1 в Startup (чтобы как только приложение стало активно) классе зовем данный контроллер (общаются два апи через Refit...) и таким образом
как только api1 запускается, api2 просматривает нашу временную таблицу с объектами, которые не были синхронизированны. и повторяет процедуру CRUD (записывает, удаляет, изменяет...)

```cs
public Task SendUnsynchronizedObjectsAsync()
{
    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
        var dbSet = dbContext.Set<ObjectsoSendToApi1>(); // наша временная таблица

        var objetctsToSynchronize = dbSet.Include(s => s.Object).ToList(); 
        // include чтобы добавить основной объект

        Task[] toAwait = new Task[objetctsToSynchronize.Count];

        // берем все объекты из временной таблицы
        for (var i = 0; i < objetctsToSynchronize.Count; i++)
        {
            toAwait[i] = SendToApi1ForSaveAsync(objetctsToSynchronize[i].Object);
            /* метод SendToApi1ForSaveAsync повторно сохраняет...
            и catch если повторно api1 не отвечает и так по кругу... */
        }

        // и удаляем объекты из временной таблицы
        dbSet.RemoveRange(objetctsToSynchronize); 
        
        Task.WaitAll(toAwait); 

        dbContext.SaveChanges(); // сохраняем изменения
    });
}
```

Comment: 1) Set -- порядок изменений у вас не важен (consraints)?
2) SaveChanges бы после WaitAll, а то потеряете

Comment: 3) если обычный апи2 и хук сработают вперемешку -- в старой базе будет не последняя версия

Comment: на счет SaveChanges исправила, спасибо, не совсем поняла consraints, наверно не наткнулась еще, если не сложно поясните.

Comment: третий пункт: мне надо подумать, но мы помним что мобильное приложение работает оффлайн и данные синхронизируют переодически а не асинхронно,
и вот позволю себе поразмыслить, если пользователь например отправил объект и сбой и как Вы говорите они паралельно работают, но это же тот же save(SendToApi1ForSaveAsync) и он берет последние изменения, разве не так?

Comment: Я же описал полное решение в ответе ... 1) Вы используете Set измененных объектов. _Порядок_ изменений теряется. Если в таблице есть связи -- может не работать. Например, добавили родителя, потом ребенка. А у вас ребенок добавится первым и попытается сослаться на родителя, которого нет. 3) У вас: меняем первый раз -- не вышло, отложили в таблицу. меняем второй раз -- вышло, пишем сразу. Потом просыпается хук и затирает изменения второго раза первым.

Comment: Вам нужно синхронизировать не просто объекты, а **упорядоченные изменения** этих объектов -- как минимум плюс одно поле updateId, которое primary key; и пишите **все** изменения через таблицу изменений, а не только неудачные.

Comment: Очень приятно ваше участие, так как новичкам как я, оно и правда необходимо. Благодарю. 1) пока веду тесты, потом отпишусь. 3) я только что протестировала, и могу сказать следующее: (сценарий) Я изменила объект, отключила апи1 и соответсвенно объект сохранился во временной таблице, затем я опять изменила объект и в момент сихнронизации с мобильного включила оба апи чтобы сихронизация прошла успешно, БазаДанных-последние изменения взялись в счет. Я breakPoint-ы понаставила еще раз проверила и думаю такое врятли возможно, потому что вначале отвечает хук затем данные начинают синхронизацию.

Comment: На счет "Я же описал полное решение в ответе ..." да и я проголосовала за. НО, порой мне тоже получается сказать , что именно сделать нужно, но когда дело доходит до кода не всегда получается, именно поэтому я пошла от дороги, которая меня повела, вначале создала что то что звало бы апи1 итд...отсюда и хук, поэтому ответ дать не всегда помогает, возможно потому что практики у меня не так много и не достаточно просто сказать человеским языком и я раз такая на машинный перевела 

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112651/discussion-between-dev18-and-sergei-kirjanov).